# MySQL, joining a table where you require the max value from the second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below query:

```
              SELECT users_service.id, name
              FROM users_service
              LEFT JOIN 

              (SELECT * FROM activity)
              
              activity ON (users_service.id = activity.user_service_id)
              WHERE admin_id = 1
```

However, this returns as many results from the activity table as exist, ie multiple activity results for each admin_id entry.

I desire to return only the latest row from the activity table for each admin_id.

This could be entry_date or id.

I tried using distinct & max and limit 1, but these all produced strange behavior.

Comment: And what column indicates the last activity?

Comment: Please add some representative data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify the column by which you determine the most recent activity. I call it `datetime_col` in the solution below:

```
SELECT users_service.id
     , name
  FROM users_service usv
   LEFT 
  JOIN activity act
      on act.users_service.id = usv.user_service_id
    and act.datetime_col = (select max(datetime_col)
                           from activity act_
                           WHERE act_.user_service_id= act.user_service_id)
```

Comment: I found this solution easiest to understand.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT us.id, a.name
FROM users_service us LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.user_service id ORDER BY ? DESC) as seqnum
      FROM activity
     ) a
    ON u.id = a.user_service_id AND seqnum = 1
WHERE u.admin_id = 1;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the "most recent", which your question doesn't clarify.